# Boiling tap water in Paris

Tags: france, paris, tap-water

I am visiting Paris.

In the accommodation given to me, I was told I can drink tap water. I was drinking from sometime. Few days back I boiled the water. A layer formed on surface of the water, when I tried to remove it, I can see a white powered type content.

The base of the steel utensil in which I boiled the water also has a layer of some white substance.

Is it normal?[image]

Comment: It's common for water to contain dissolved materials which do not evaporate. The white substance is probably mostly calcium carbonate - also known as limescale. (Assuming that veseel is dry. If there is still water in there that is weirder - some kind of sdeiment?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be travel related

Comment: @CMaster I don’t understand what do you mean it is not travel related.. I am visiting here and I want to ask if this would create any issue while I am still here…

Comment: The vessel has water.. it is not dry.. this is what I see when I use it for 3/4 times to boil water before I clean again…

Comment: Just because something happens while you're traveling doesn't necessarily make it a travel question

Comment: @CMaster mineral sediment begins to appear before the water evaporates completely.

Comment: Have you tried boiling tap water at home (wherever that is)? Was it different?

Comment: @StuartF yes, it is very much different. I don't remember seeing this  till now...

Comment: @Berend: This a very common issue that most people encounter specifically when travelling — judging tap water quality in unfamiliar settings — so it seems pretty reasonably on-topic.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Simply this is so common an experience for many of us that it is somewhat funny that somebody has to ask what it is. :-))

Comment: Damn. That's some really hard water lol

Comment: @Gábor On a lighter note, I hope people visiting India would also understand why we find it funny when tourists ask some obvious things.. :D

Comment: How hard tap water ever may be. It's not supposed to contain particles.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Paris water is **very** [hard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_water), which means that there is a lot of particles and mineral content in the water

What you see is a buildup of minerals and limescale, this is destined to happen when you boil hard water.

It is normal and not harmful in any way. Tap water is definitely very drinkable in Paris (I drink tap water myself as a local)

Comment: Often referred as limescale, which builds up in devices, such as when you use tap water to iron your clothing for example. Edit: But someone already mentioned it in the comment section of the question.

Comment: Hard water is actually healthier if your bladders are not damaged in specific way.

Comment: @fraxinus Do you mean mineral water?

Comment: No. I mean hard water - the one that comes from limestone wells or springs.

Comment: As an aside, if it worries you in any way, just boil water with a tablespoon of citric acid added (probably readily available in any grocery store). Simply rinse, absolutely harmless otherwise (lemon). Common vinegar is just as good but has a stronger odor and taste.

Comment: I wouldn't say hard water has a lot of "particles" - Paris will filter the water to remove those.  What it has, is a lot of (mainly) calcium carbonate dissolved in it.

Comment: There is a plan to make Paris water less hard (and less polluted), but it is not for the next few years: https://www.debatpublic.fr/eau-potable-idf (in French).

Comment: I would say that Paris water is moderately hard. It's noticeable but I have seen harder water elsewhere in France. Mineral content is highest in the centre of Paris and the ARS calls it “[moyennement calcaire](https://www.eaudeparis.fr/sites/default/files/import/ARS/2021_UDI_CENTRE.pdf)” Wikipedia has a map where [Paris is orange](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duret%C3%A9_de_l%27eau) (“très dure”) but the threshold is 30ºf and Paris tap water is just under that limit.

Answer (score 6):

As already answered, this is hard water mineral deposits. Perfectly normal in many areas. While you encountered this first in your travels, in some areas you have soft water and hard water in the same city, depending on the local water sources.

The important thing is to **not** try to scrape it off. The solution (literally) is acid. I use white vinegar, but there are many other things you can use. Put a little vinegar in the pot, heat it up for a few minutes and your problem will be (dis)solved with no scrubbing.

Answer (score 6):

> In the accommodation given to me, I was told I can drink tap water.

Tap water is France's [most controlled aliment](https://sante.gouv.fr/sante-et-environnement/eaux/article/le-controle-de-la-qualite-de-l-eau-du-robinet). You can check its parameters on an [interactive map](https://sante.gouv.fr/sante-et-environnement/eaux/eau) (which, in the French tradition, does not work at this moment when I tried to look up today's values for Paris )

**EDIT**: I found another (better) source specifically for Paris: https://qualite.eaudeparis.fr/. You can check where the water in your exact location comes from and the latest results (done several times per day or even per hour, but the results published on the site are a bit dated ("March 2023" for a check on 2023-05-21)

Bonus information (unrelated to the question): the site also has a list of water points in Paris at https://fontaine.eaudeparis.fr/

Comment: Thank you. It said "L'adresse sélectionnée est desservie par l'unité de distribution CENTRE

L’Unité de Distribution (UDI) CENTRE est alimentée par les sources du Loing et de la Voulzie traitées aux usines de Longueville et de Sorques et acheminée via l’aqueduc du Loing jusqu’au réservoir Montsouris."

Comment: Translation says "The selected address is served by the CENTER distribution unit

The CENTER Distribution Unit (UDI) is supplied by the Loing and Voulzie springs treated at the Longueville and Sorques plants and routed via the Loing aqueduct to the Montsouris reservoir."

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: you then need to click on the left popup on "Consulter le dernier rapport de contrôle sanitaire" which then gives you the detailed analysis. The rightmost column shows the number of times the norm was not met (should be 0)

Answer (score -11):

I wouldn't suggest you to drink tap water as a precaution.
A recent study has shown that it has a concentration of pesticide over 8 times the allowed regulated amount for a few years.
Though there is no immediate consequence, this particular kind of pesticide is proved to be cancerous.

So if I were you, I wouldn't drink Paris tap water (I myself live near Paris), but there are no immediate consequences, it's just a risk, it's up to you if you're willing to take the risk

Edit: Ok since some people want sources here you go, I didn't want to include any because it's in french OBVIOUSLY, so good luck :
https://www.anses.fr/fr/system/files/LABORATOIRE2022AST0255Ra.pdf

Don't just start downvoting when you don't know and you're probably not even french, it is widely known and even been on the news a few weeks ago.

-> Ce rapport révèle en effet l’existence de métabolites de Chlorothalonil dans l'eau courante de nos robinets. Il s’agit de résidus d'un pesticide pourtant interdit depuis 2019.

TLDR; This report reveals the existance of particles of "Chlorothalonil" in our tap water. They are residues of a pesticide forbidden since 2019.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more compelling if it cited a reputable source/link.

Comment: This is not a low quality answer, so no need to flag it as such. It may well be a wrong answer, no need to flag for that. Vote down or ask for further information.

Comment: Considering the environmental impact of drinking bottled water and their dubious health benefits (do you really think *no* plastic leaches into water over its storage???), I would think that pushing **unsourced** health scares is rather off topic.  Lived in Paris 10 years, was A-OK with drinking its water from tap.  More info about plastics @ https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9103198/

Comment: Read my updated post

Comment: don't come all angry because I didn't put sources, just ask for sources like the first person, ceejayoz did. And I'll provide.
By the way "Italian Philosophers 4 Monica", did you know cancer doesn't show up in the span of 10 years ? And do you understand the concept of "risk" ?
risk : The **possibility** of suffering harm or loss; danger.
A factor, thing, element, or course involving **uncertain danger**; a hazard. Just because you drink it doesn't mean you will undoubtedly have cancer, it poses a risk.

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant. Just because you don't have cancer doesn't mean someone else can't have it, please go study more science

Comment: The source is interesting, but I don't see any specific reference to the water in Paris. While valid, I don't see that any of the concerns raised in this answer specifically answer the question about residue from boiling water.
As to know which is more harmful, of bottled water in general vs tap water, this answer only provides data about one side, and doesn't consider any of the risks associated with drinking bottle water. (Unless you were suggesting to stop drinking water altogether?)

Comment: @njzk2, well it's a study which was made on March 2023, in Maisons-Alfort, a city located in Ile-de-France (Paris region). As you pointed, this answer is not related to "boiling" tap water in Paris, rather "tap water in Paris" in general. Well yeah sure ! Of course drinking "bottled water" as you call it (I don't like this appelation, it's "mineral water" because it contains natural minerals) CAN be harmful for some people because of the possible high concentration of HCO3 (Potassium) it can contain depending on the source of the mineral water, it surely is not contaminated cancerous pesticide

Comment: Bouncing back on my answer, only a few percentage of the population that has a certain medical condition is subject to severe harm if consuming too much Potassium, by having a balanced diet the high concentration of potassium in mineral water won't do any harm, so it won't be the case for probably any of us reading this right now.
Page 28 on the scientific study is where it's classed by region.

Comment: You never specifically mentioned mineral water before. You know, of course, that in France this only applies to a specific category of bottled water (not, to, for example, Cristaline). There are other issues with bottled waters, especially when packaged in plastic bottles. However, you seem very certain that "[mineral water] surely is not contaminated cancerous pesticide". Do you have sources for that?

Comment: Upvoted. France tap water is notoriously unsafe. Not only do ANSES reports frequently warn about presence of pesticides and their metabolites but many other independent labs come to same conclusion. You can't have strong productive agriculture and safe water tables at the same time.
Paris tap water come from water tables lying underneath farming areas. That's why French consumer spend money on mineral water from mountainous (farming free) regions. No big wonder.